# How to create a chart that everyone can see from a list that is restricted?

Tags: list, lookup-column, chart

I am trying to create a chart from a list that has restricted viewing but the chart has to be visible to everyone. The problem I am having with my current work flow is everyone can see the charts but the data in the charts is only visible to those who can see the restricted list.

My current work flow is as follows:

List A - Restricted viewing

List B - Lookup for List A and counts related. No Restrictions.

Chart A - read data from List B. No Restrictions. (Needs to be visible everyone)

Currently Chart A is only visible by those who can see List A. I need this to be visible everyone and List a need to stay restricted.

Any help on this one would be greatly appreciated. :)

Thanks

Shawn

Comment: Do you have to have restricted read? You could always have a workflow that creates a copy of the list item in another list that is not restricted.

Comment: what is counts related on list B?

Comment: Yes the data need to be restricted. I am fairly new to sharepoint and have looked at workflows but I am not sure how to set it up.

Comment: counts related from my understanding of it occurs when you have a lookup on a field from a table and the create a lookup field in the second table back to the destination table. basically it counts the number of occurrences of an item in a list .

Comment: The only way to do this is programming a solution or programming a page with javascript. I see no other way to do this unless programming.

Answer (score 0):

this should work and is simple to implement. without it being a coded method I would suggest:

remove the permission from list A.

so its visible to all.

on the list click on site actions and edit. This will edit the page for the current default list view called allitems.aspx

you should see the list as a webpart. top right of the webpart click on the drop down to edit the webpart properties -> to the right of the page on the webpart properties click on the advanced tab and expand -> where it says target audience put in the restricted sharepoint group that you want to give access.
once done click ok and save/checkin page

allitems.aspx now has a restricted view of the list that is only visible to a specific sharepoint group like before.

now

create a custom view on list A. my example I will call it lvA. show what you want like on list B but do it for list A. Set the count like you did for list B but on list A instead.

click ok when finished to create the view. it will redirect you back to the list but this time showing you the new custom list view - look at the url it should say the list view name and has a prefix of .aspx

once your on that page edit the page -> site actions -> edit.

on the webpart for that view edit its properties -> top right of webpart click the drop down and edit properties -> right side you should see its properties -> under advanced tab you can set the audience targeting to the default site viewers group that should have read only -> make sure everyone is in that group or create a new security group that contains all users. click ok and save/check in page.

so you now have two list views for list A. one of them is lvA that gives a view to all users to read from the list and the other is allItems which is the default view that is restricted to a specific group.

now within your chart you can use your new view in my case lvA that should display what ever I want from list A.

hope I make sense, seems like a lot but its not. let me know how you get on.